# Send text and click ENTER on expath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I clicked the text box but I am unable to send a text.

```
divselected = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add a public comment...')]")[0].click()

divselected.send_keys("Talk-Talk")
```

Unable to add comments and press enter.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"?  You don't know how to do it, or you tried something specific and it didn't work?

Comment: I am trying but unable to put text inside text box after click()

Comment: divselected[0].send_keys("Talk-Talk")

Comment: By click() text box is getting clicked but trying to input text and then press enter.

Comment: Did you try `divselected.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` ?

Comment: Is that element a textarea?  Pressing Enter in a textarea won't submit the form.

Comment: I am trying to post a comment on youtube comment box.

Answer (score 0):

I did some search and I think this should work, just `clear` and send `return` key.

```
divselected = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add a public comment...')]")[0].click()
divselected.clear()
divselected.send_keys("Talk-Talk")
divselected.send_keys("Keys.RETURN")
```

Comment: `Keys.RETURN` should not be in quotes.

Comment: Not working.   divselected = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add a public comment...')]")[0]
    divselected.click()
    divselected.clear()
    divselected.send_keys("Talk-Talk")
    divselected.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

Comment: Since you are trying to comment on youtube, what about get element by id?

Answer (score 0):

You wrong variable initialize for `divselected`, remove *`.click()`*.
So, it's should like this:

```
divselected = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add a public comment...')]")[0]
divselected.click()
divselected.send_keys('Talk-Talk')
divselected.submit()
```

Or if *`.submit()`* doesn't work, use *`.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`*:

```
#following import
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

divselected.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

But in this case if you want get the first element (refers to your index `[0]`), actually you don't need ***`.find_elements_*`***. You can use ***`.find_element_`***(without `s`):

```
divselected = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add a public comment...')]")
```